# How can i have multiple select options for a single image?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I am using `SceneKit` to import a 3d image model of a human body. When i select a particular location point in the image, i want the app to recognize the body part and perform a different function for each part. How do i go about implementing this? What is the best way to do this?

P.s. when the image is rotated it shows a different view. I need the app to be able to recognize the body part even when it is rotated by the user. Any guidance as to how to proceed would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple SceneKit picking example.

The scene is setup in the `viewDidLoad`, for your use case I'd expect a scene would be loaded from file (best done in another method). This file will hopefully have the different components you wish to pick as separate components in a tree-like hierarchy. The author of this 3D body model will have hopefully labelled these components appropriately so that your code can identify what to do when your left-femur is selected (and not comp2345).

For a complex model expect several 'hits' for any xy coordinate as you will be returned all nodes intersected by the hit ray. You may wish to only use the first hit.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scenekitView: SCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = SCNScene()

        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0))
        boxNode.name = "box"
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1))
        sphereNode.name = "sphere"
        sphereNode.position = SCNVector3Make(2, 0, 0)
        boxNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

        let torusNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNTorus(ringRadius: 1, pipeRadius: 0.3))
        torusNode.name = "torus"
        torusNode.position = SCNVector3Make(2, 0, 0)
        sphereNode.addChildNode(torusNode)

        scenekitView.scene = scene
        scenekitView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        scenekitView.allowsCameraControl = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        //get the first touch location in screen coordinates
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }

        //convert the screen coordinates to view coordinates as the SCNView make not take
        //up the entire screen.
        let pt = touch.locationInView(self.scenekitView)

        //pass a ray from the points 2d coordinates into the scene, returning a list
        //of objects it hits
        let hits = self.scenekitView.hitTest(pt, options: nil)

        for hit in hits {
            //do something with each hit
            print("touched ", hit.node.name!)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info brother. My image model will be a COLLADA file. When i import it, it will be an entire entity in itself. You have used different nodes in your answer. My situation is that the entire image i import will be one node. Is there any way i can refer to a single node in different ways? or if i can break my image node into multiple child nodes that i can refer to?

Comment: Yes, I expected it would be a single Collada file. However when you import it into SceneKit, it should contain a number of nodes. A Collada file can represent an entire scene (of course a scene may only contain one node).

Comment: Could you give me a brief on what documentation or material i should go through to create multiple nodes into a sample dae file?

Comment: @Jobs It's dependent on what 3D modelling tool you're using. I'd start by adding the dae file to your XCode project and viewing using the [scene editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scene_kit_editor/Articles/AboutSceneKitEditor.html). The "entities list" will show the hierarchy of nodes within your dae. If there is only one node, with no child nodes, then you may need to split your existing model.

I'm a [Blender (tutorials link)](https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/) rookie, but could build the same scene as is programatically constructed with a few clicks.